# ruby (rails) Net::HTTPResponse undefined method closed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, net-http

Ruby-on-Rails, Net::HTTPResponse
NoMethodError:undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass

Hello, I have faced an issue:
I use the RSpec framework and I need to mock a response within a method which I test.

here is a sample of the method:

```
def perform_request
    response = DataClient.new.request(arg: 'some_arg')
    # do some thing with the response
end 

RSpec file:
    describe '#perform_request'
      let(:response) do
        Net::HTTPResponse.new(1.0, 200, "OK")
      end

      let(:double_response) {double('DataClient', request: response)}

      before do
       response.body = {some_key:some_value}.to_json
       allow(DataClient).to receive(:new).and_return(double_response)   
      end

     it 'returns a response body' do
       MyClass.new.perform_request
       expect(response.body).to eq({some_key:some_value}.to_json)
     end 
   end
```

the problem happens when I try to call the 'body' method for the Net::HTTPResponse instance to read the body of it.

It throws the NoMethodError with the message  "undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass" which I have no idea about.

I have tried to search for any explanation with question variations such as 'Net::HTTPResponse body undefined method `closed?'', 'Ruby Net:: HTTPResponse body undefined method`closed?', 'Ruby undefined method `closed?' but couldn't find any relevant answer.

In advance, I have to say I can't use any other client library except the Net:: HTTP without any wrappers. Please don't advice it.

The point of the question is not just to get an explanation but also to get advice how to solve the problem.
Thank you in advance for any explanation and advice.

Comment: If you're stubbing the response, why do you even need to make the request in your test? What exactly are you testing?

Comment: @lacostenycoder, thank you for the question, could you please clarify how it is relevant to the point of the problem and why do you think it does matter?  The question is why when I try to call the reader-method 'body', - it causes the exception.  It occurs here: `expect(response.body)` , but here `response.body = {some_key:some_value}` I've set the value for the body. According to the documentation [ https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html ] it has to return a value but I got the ' "undefined method `closed?' instead.

Comment: Is there any code in `MyClass` that calls a function called `closed?` through a callback or while trying to process the response in some way? `.closed?` definitely seems like a method in your code, which could explain why no relevant answers could be found. Does this function work when actually being called (as in, without using RSpec)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is thrown because the instance of `Net::HTTPResponse` you created in your test setup is trying to verify if the connection from which it expects to get data is closed.

I would not bother with creating an actual instance of `Net::HTTPRequest` in your test setup. All your class knows is that `DataClient.new.request` returns an object that responds to `.body`. I would change your setup as follows:

```
let(:response){ instance_double(Net::HTTPResponse, body: response_body)}
```

```
let(:response_body) { { key: :value }.to_json }
```

Using an instance double instead of a real instance allows you to not have to worry about the actual implementation details of the class, while still getting the assurance that you are calling methods the class supports.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I've done very close to it except I need an entire response object with a status code, not only body. Next step in my code the response is passed to a parser which handles that fields so I have decided to create a class instead of hash, `  class HttpResponse
        attr_accessor :code, :msg, :body
        def initialize(code, msg, body)
          @code = code
          @msg = msg
          @body = body
        end
      end `

Comment: ok but you have not exactly asked a question, so what I did was explain WHY you are getting an error.  If you have a specific question, you should either revise your question, or accept this answer.

Comment: Can't you just add the response status to the stubbed response object?

Comment: @lacostenycoder it works. Thank you. Sorry for the thoughtlessness)).

Answer (score 3):

To debug these kinds of errors, `gem install pry` + `gem install yard` are your friends.  Then you can run a pry console and see what's happening.  In my case I did this inside pry console:

```
response = Net::HTTPResponse.new(1.0, 200, "OK")
response.body # raises same exception you got
```

Here's why you're getting the error if examine the code from `response.rb`

`response.body` calls `read_body` which calls `stream_check` which calls `.closed?` on `@socket` which you don't have since you're not making an HTTP request but mocking a response.

You can do this from pry as well:

```
show-method Net::HTTPResponse
# now you're in a less session so find your methods:
/def body # to find the method
/def read_body # find it
/def stream_check # and here's your error
```

Here's the code from response.rb stdlib

```
class Net::HTTPResponse
  class << self
    # true if the response has a body.
    def body_permitted?
      self::HAS_BODY
    end

    def exception_type   # :nodoc: internal use only
      self::EXCEPTION_TYPE
    end

    def read_new(sock)   #:nodoc: internal use only
      httpv, code, msg = read_status_line(sock)
      res = response_class(code).new(httpv, code, msg)
      each_response_header(sock) do |k,v|
        res.add_field k, v
      end
      res
    end

    private

    def read_status_line(sock)
      str = sock.readline
      m = /\AHTTP(?:\/(\d+\.\d+))?\s+(\d\d\d)(?:\s+(.*))?\z/in.match(str) or
        raise Net::HTTPBadResponse, "wrong status line: #{str.dump}"
      m.captures
    end

    def response_class(code)
      CODE_TO_OBJ[code] or
      CODE_CLASS_TO_OBJ[code[0,1]] or
      Net::HTTPUnknownResponse
    end

    def each_response_header(sock)
      key = value = nil
      while true
        line = sock.readuntil("\n", true).sub(/\s+\z/, '')
        break if line.empty?
        if line[0] == ?\s or line[0] == ?\t and value
          value << ' ' unless value.empty?
          value << line.strip
        else
          yield key, value if key
          key, value = line.strip.split(/\s*:\s*/, 2)
          raise Net::HTTPBadResponse, 'wrong header line format' if value.nil?
        end
      end
      yield key, value if key
    end
  end

  # next is to fix bug in RDoc, where the private inside class << self
  # spills out.
  public

  include Net::HTTPHeader

  def initialize(httpv, code, msg)   #:nodoc: internal use only
    @http_version = httpv
    @code         = code
    @message      = msg
    initialize_http_header nil
    @body = nil
    @read = false
    @uri  = nil
    @decode_content = false
  end

  # The HTTP version supported by the server.
  attr_reader :http_version

  # The HTTP result code string. For example, '302'.  You can also
  # determine the response type by examining which response subclass
  # the response object is an instance of.
  attr_reader :code

  # The HTTP result message sent by the server. For example, 'Not Found'.
  attr_reader :message
  alias msg message   # :nodoc: obsolete

  # The URI used to fetch this response.  The response URI is only available
  # if a URI was used to create the request.
  attr_reader :uri

  # Set to true automatically when the request did not contain an
  # Accept-Encoding header from the user.
  attr_accessor :decode_content

  def inspect
    "#<#{self.class} #{@code} #{@message} readbody=#{@read}>"
  end

  #
  # response <-> exception relationship
  #

  def code_type   #:nodoc:
    self.class
  end

  def error!   #:nodoc:
    message = @code
    message += ' ' + @message.dump if @message
    raise error_type().new(message, self)
  end

  def error_type   #:nodoc:
    self.class::EXCEPTION_TYPE
  end

  # Raises an HTTP error if the response is not 2xx (success).
  def value
    error! unless self.kind_of?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
  end

  def uri= uri # :nodoc:
    @uri = uri.dup if uri
  end

  #
  # header (for backward compatibility only; DO NOT USE)
  #

  def response   #:nodoc:
    warn "Net::HTTPResponse#response is obsolete", uplevel: 1 if $VERBOSE
    self
  end

  def header   #:nodoc:
    warn "Net::HTTPResponse#header is obsolete", uplevel: 1 if $VERBOSE
    self
  end

  def read_header   #:nodoc:
    warn "Net::HTTPResponse#read_header is obsolete", uplevel: 1 if $VERBOSE
    self
  end

  #
  # body
  #

  def reading_body(sock, reqmethodallowbody)  #:nodoc: internal use only
    @socket = sock
    @body_exist = reqmethodallowbody && self.class.body_permitted?
    begin
      yield
      self.body   # ensure to read body
    ensure
      @socket = nil
    end
  end

  # Gets the entity body returned by the remote HTTP server.
  #
  # If a block is given, the body is passed to the block, and
  # the body is provided in fragments, as it is read in from the socket.
  #
  # Calling this method a second or subsequent time for the same
  # HTTPResponse object will return the value already read.
  #
  #   http.request_get('/index.html') {|res|
  #     puts res.read_body
  #   }
  #
  #   http.request_get('/index.html') {|res|
  #     p res.read_body.object_id   # 538149362
  #     p res.read_body.object_id   # 538149362
  #   }
  #
  #   # using iterator
  #   http.request_get('/index.html') {|res|
  #     res.read_body do |segment|
  #       print segment
  #     end
  #   }
  #
  def read_body(dest = nil, &block)
    if @read
      raise IOError, "#{self.class}\#read_body called twice" if dest or block
      return @body
    end
    to = procdest(dest, block)
    stream_check
    if @body_exist
      read_body_0 to
      @body = to
    else
      @body = nil
    end
    @read = true

    @body
  end

  # Returns the full entity body.
  #
  # Calling this method a second or subsequent time will return the
  # string already read.
  #
  #   http.request_get('/index.html') {|res|
  #     puts res.body
  #   }
  #
  #   http.request_get('/index.html') {|res|
  #     p res.body.object_id   # 538149362
  #     p res.body.object_id   # 538149362
  #   }
  #
  def body
    read_body()
  end

  # Because it may be necessary to modify the body, Eg, decompression
  # this method facilitates that.
  def body=(value)
    @body = value
  end

  alias entity body   #:nodoc: obsolete

  private

  ##
  # Checks for a supported Content-Encoding header and yields an Inflate
  # wrapper for this response's socket when zlib is present.  If the
  # Content-Encoding is not supported or zlib is missing, the plain socket is
  # yielded.
  #
  # If a Content-Range header is present, a plain socket is yielded as the
  # bytes in the range may not be a complete deflate block.

  def inflater # :nodoc:
    return yield @socket unless Net::HTTP::HAVE_ZLIB
    return yield @socket unless @decode_content
    return yield @socket if self['content-range']

    v = self['content-encoding']
    case v&.downcase
    when 'deflate', 'gzip', 'x-gzip' then
      self.delete 'content-encoding'

      inflate_body_io = Inflater.new(@socket)

      begin
        yield inflate_body_io
      ensure
        orig_err = $!
        begin
          inflate_body_io.finish
        rescue => err
          raise orig_err || err
        end
      end
    when 'none', 'identity' then
      self.delete 'content-encoding'

      yield @socket
    else
      yield @socket
    end
  end

  def read_body_0(dest)
    inflater do |inflate_body_io|
      if chunked?
        read_chunked dest, inflate_body_io
        return
      end

      @socket = inflate_body_io

From: /Users/lacoste/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb @ line 17:
Class name: Net::HTTPResponse
Number of lines: 403

class Net::HTTPResponse
  class << self
    # true if the response has a body.
    def body_permitted?
      self::HAS_BODY
    end

    def exception_type   # :nodoc: internal use only
      self::EXCEPTION_TYPE
    end

    def read_new(sock)   #:nodoc: internal use only
      httpv, code, msg = read_status_line(sock)
      res = response_class(code).new(httpv, code, msg)
      each_response_header(sock) do |k,v|
        res.add_field k, v
      end
      res
    end

    private

    def read_status_line(sock)
      str = sock.readline
      m = /\AHTTP(?:\/(\d+\.\d+))?\s+(\d\d\d)(?:\s+(.*))?\z/in.match(str) or
        raise Net::HTTPBadResponse, "wrong status line: #{str.dump}"
      m.captures
    end

    def response_class(code)
      CODE_TO_OBJ[code] or
      CODE_CLASS_TO_OBJ[code[0,1]] or
      Net::HTTPUnknownResponse
    end

    def each_response_header(sock)
      key = value = nil
      while true
        line = sock.readuntil("\n", true).sub(/\s+\z/, '')
        break if line.empty?
        if line[0] == ?\s or line[0] == ?\t and value
          value << ' ' unless value.empty?
          value << line.strip
        else
          yield key, value if key
          key, value = line.strip.split(/\s*:\s*/, 2)
          raise Net::HTTPBadResponse, 'wrong header line format' if value.nil?
        end
      end
      yield key, value if key
    end
  end

  # next is to fix bug in RDoc, where the private inside class << self
  # spills out.
  public

  include Net::HTTPHeader

  def initialize(httpv, code, msg)   #:nodoc: internal use only
    @http_version = httpv
    @code         = code
    @message      = msg
    initialize_http_header nil
    @body = nil
    @read = false
    @uri  = nil
    @decode_content = false
  end

  # The HTTP version supported by the server.
  attr_reader :http_version

  # The HTTP result code string. For example, '302'.  You can also
  # determine the response type by examining which response subclass
  # the response object is an instance of.
  attr_reader :code

  # The HTTP result message sent by the server. For example, 'Not Found'.
  attr_reader :message
  alias msg message   # :nodoc: obsolete

  # The URI used to fetch this response.  The response URI is only available
  # if a URI was used to create the request.
  attr_reader :uri

  # Set to true automatically when the request did not contain an
  # Accept-Encoding header from the user.
  attr_accessor :decode_content

  def inspect
    "#<#{self.class} #{@code} #{@message} readbody=#{@read}>"
  end

  #
  # response <-> exception relationship
  #

  def code_type   #:nodoc:
    self.class
  end

  def error!   #:nodoc:
    message = @code
    message += ' ' + @message.dump if @message
    raise error_type().new(message, self)
  end

  def error_type   #:nodoc:
    self.class::EXCEPTION_TYPE
  end

  # Raises an HTTP error if the response is not 2xx (success).
  def value
    error! unless self.kind_of?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
  end

  def uri= uri # :nodoc:
    @uri = uri.dup if uri
  end

  #
  # header (for backward compatibility only; DO NOT USE)
  #

  def response   #:nodoc:
    warn "Net::HTTPResponse#response is obsolete", uplevel: 1 if $VERBOSE
    self
  end

  def header   #:nodoc:
    warn "Net::HTTPResponse#header is obsolete", uplevel: 1 if $VERBOSE
    self
  end

  def read_header   #:nodoc:
    warn "Net::HTTPResponse#read_header is obsolete", uplevel: 1 if $VERBOSE
    self
  end

  #
  # body
  #

  def reading_body(sock, reqmethodallowbody)  #:nodoc: internal use only
    @socket = sock
    @body_exist = reqmethodallowbody && self.class.body_permitted?
    begin
      yield
      self.body   # ensure to read body
    ensure
      @socket = nil
    end
  end

  # Gets the entity body returned by the remote HTTP server.
  #
  # If a block is given, the body is passed to the block, and
  # the body is provided in fragments, as it is read in from the socket.
  #
  # Calling this method a second or subsequent time for the same
  # HTTPResponse object will return the value already read.
  #
  #   http.request_get('/index.html') {|res|
  #     puts res.read_body
  #   }
  #
  #   http.request_get('/index.html') {|res|
  #     p res.read_body.object_id   # 538149362
  #     p res.read_body.object_id   # 538149362
  #   }
  #
  #   # using iterator
  #   http.request_get('/index.html') {|res|
  #     res.read_body do |segment|
  #       print segment
  #     end
  #   }
  #
  def read_body(dest = nil, &block)
    if @read
      raise IOError, "#{self.class}\#read_body called twice" if dest or block
      return @body
    end
    to = procdest(dest, block)
    stream_check
    if @body_exist
      read_body_0 to
      @body = to
    else
      @body = nil
    end
    @read = true

    @body
  end

  # Returns the full entity body.
  #
  # Calling this method a second or subsequent time will return the
  # string already read.
  #
  #   http.request_get('/index.html') {|res|
  #     puts res.body
  #   }
  #
  #   http.request_get('/index.html') {|res|
  #     p res.body.object_id   # 538149362
  #     p res.body.object_id   # 538149362
  #   }
  #
  def body
    read_body()
  end

  # Because it may be necessary to modify the body, Eg, decompression
  # this method facilitates that.
  def body=(value)
    @body = value
  end

  alias entity body   #:nodoc: obsolete

  private

  ##
  # Checks for a supported Content-Encoding header and yields an Inflate
  # wrapper for this response's socket when zlib is present.  If the
  # Content-Encoding is not supported or zlib is missing, the plain socket is
  # yielded.
  #
  # If a Content-Range header is present, a plain socket is yielded as the
  # bytes in the range may not be a complete deflate block.

  def inflater # :nodoc:
    return yield @socket unless Net::HTTP::HAVE_ZLIB
    return yield @socket unless @decode_content
    return yield @socket if self['content-range']

    v = self['content-encoding']
    case v&.downcase
    when 'deflate', 'gzip', 'x-gzip' then
      self.delete 'content-encoding'

      inflate_body_io = Inflater.new(@socket)

      begin
        yield inflate_body_io
      ensure
        orig_err = $!
        begin
          inflate_body_io.finish
        rescue => err
          raise orig_err || err
        end
      end
    when 'none', 'identity' then
      self.delete 'content-encoding'

      yield @socket
    else
      yield @socket
    end
  end

  def read_body_0(dest)
    inflater do |inflate_body_io|
      if chunked?
        read_chunked dest, inflate_body_io
        return
      end

      @socket = inflate_body_io

      clen = content_length()
      if clen
        @socket.read clen, dest, true   # ignore EOF
        return
      end
      clen = range_length()
      if clen
        @socket.read clen, dest
        return
      end
      @socket.read_all dest
    end
  end

  ##
  # read_chunked reads from +@socket+ for chunk-size, chunk-extension, CRLF,
  # etc. and +chunk_data_io+ for chunk-data which may be deflate or gzip
  # encoded.
  #
  # See RFC 2616 section 3.6.1 for definitions

  def read_chunked(dest, chunk_data_io) # :nodoc:
    total = 0
    while true
      line = @socket.readline
      hexlen = line.slice(/[0-9a-fA-F]+/) or
          raise Net::HTTPBadResponse, "wrong chunk size line: #{line}"
      len = hexlen.hex
      break if len == 0
      begin
        chunk_data_io.read len, dest
      ensure
        total += len
        @socket.read 2   # \r\n
      end
    end
    until @socket.readline.empty?
      # none
    end
  end

  def stream_check
    raise IOError, 'attempt to read body out of block' if @socket.closed?
  end

  def procdest(dest, block)
    raise ArgumentError, 'both arg and block given for HTTP method' if
      dest and block
    if block
      Net::ReadAdapter.new(block)
    else
      dest || ''
    end
  end

  ##
  # Inflater is a wrapper around Net::BufferedIO that transparently inflates
  # zlib and gzip streams.

  class Inflater # :nodoc:

    ##
    # Creates a new Inflater wrapping +socket+

    def initialize socket
      @socket = socket
      # zlib with automatic gzip detection
      @inflate = Zlib::Inflate.new(32 + Zlib::MAX_WBITS)
    end

    ##
    # Finishes the inflate stream.

    def finish
      return if @inflate.total_in == 0
      @inflate.finish
    end

    ##
    # Returns a Net::ReadAdapter that inflates each read chunk into +dest+.
    #
    # This allows a large response body to be inflated without storing the
    # entire body in memory.

    def inflate_adapter(dest)
      if dest.respond_to?(:set_encoding)
        dest.set_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT)
      elsif dest.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
        dest.force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT)
      end
      block = proc do |compressed_chunk|
        @inflate.inflate(compressed_chunk) do |chunk|
          compressed_chunk.clear
          dest << chunk
        end
      end

      Net::ReadAdapter.new(block)
    end

    ##
    # Reads +clen+ bytes from the socket, inflates them, then writes them to
    # +dest+.  +ignore_eof+ is passed down to Net::BufferedIO#read
    #
    # Unlike Net::BufferedIO#read, this method returns more than +clen+ bytes.
    # At this time there is no way for a user of Net::HTTPResponse to read a
    # specific number of bytes from the HTTP response body, so this internal
    # API does not return the same number of bytes as were requested.
    #
    # See https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6492 for further discussion.

    def read clen, dest, ignore_eof = false
      temp_dest = inflate_adapter(dest)

      @socket.read clen, temp_dest, ignore_eof
    end

    ##
    # Reads the rest of the socket, inflates it, then writes it to +dest+.

    def read_all dest
      temp_dest = inflate_adapter(dest)

      @socket.read_all temp_dest
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: thank a lot for the detail explanation and for your time you have devoted to it. Might be you also have some decent solutions on how to better solve it?  Currently, I have decided to fake the response object close to how Fito von Zastrow has described below, except details which I'm going to describe in a coment for his answer, but it would be really much better to find the native soution for this.